# Excel - Compare multiple columns for any two or more cells within the same row having the same content

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I need great help here. I want to compare two cells that are in different columns but at the same row. I need to write two different products names into two different cells and i need excel to show it to me if the entered two texts exist in the same row or not. For instance, I write 'Socks' and 'Sandals' in to two different cells, and excel shows me if they exist in the same row within two seperate columns.

Ty in advance

Comment: Can you show an example of your sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to clarify your data set setup.

One potential solution =IF(MATCH(...)=MATCH(...),"match", "no match")